# Asp.net Web api 6: Use ValidationAttribute for a unique userName

Tags: validation, asp.net-web-api

I do not have much code here
But I want to create my own validation for username that will not have duplicates.

Model:

```
[Table("User")]
public partial class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    [Column("userName")]
    [StringLength(200)]
    [AllValidation(ErrorMessage = "foo")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is a required field")]
    public string UserName { get; set; } = null!;
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "The password should be between 3 characters to 50")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is a required field")]
    public string Password { get; set; } = null!;
    //[Column(TypeName = "date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}")]

    public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }
    public string? Token { get; set; }
}
```

ValidationAttribute:

```
public class AllValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly TalkBackDbContext _context;
    

    public AllValidationAttribute(TalkBackDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return _context.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName == name)!.ToString()!;
    }
}
```

I get an error when I try to insert ErrorMessage into an attribute

this is the error:

[image]

Comment: what is the error that you are getting

Comment: @CodingMytra I edited the post with the error

Comment: the error is not because of ErrorMessage but due to constructor of your AllValidationAttribute which expects the TalkBackDbContext.

Comment: So how can I solve this?

Comment: check ans below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this.

remove it from constructor and override IsValid method.

```
    public class AllValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
       private string username;
       
       protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, 
        ValidationContext validationContext)
       {
           var _context = (TalkBackDbContext )validationContext
                      .GetService(typeof(TalkBackDbContext ));
          username = value.ToString();
          
         
          if(!_context.Users.Any(cus => cus.UserName == value.ToString()))
          {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
          }
          else
          {
            return new ValidationResult
                ("Unique Name expected" + value.ToString());
          } 
       }

       public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
       {
         return "Expected Uniquename" + username;
       }
   }
```

Comment: FormatErrorMessage(string name) , here "name" is not the username but text which you pass from attribute, are you going to set username from attribute ?

Comment: then anyways this logic will not work. Format message is just for formatting the error message. actuall validation happens in IsValid method only. check for uniqueness and return true false based on that. in FormatErrorMessage you just write custom message. if you want to include the UserName also then set privately and return from FormatErrorMessage

Comment: check updated ans.

Comment: you can correct the condition by checking against null and also you have to change the return value also.

Comment: I have updated the code again. check it. again i have shown the idea how it can be done now you also have to do some work.